# Using Residue to solve partial fraction decompositions

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, partial-fractions

a) $Res(3i)$ for $R(z) = \frac{z^2-9}{(z^2+9)^2}$

So I solved this by using the formula is:

$\lim_{z \to 3i} \frac{1}{1!} \frac{d}{dz} [(z^2+9)^2 \times \frac{z^2-9}{(z^2+9)^2}]$

$\lim_{z \to 3i}  \frac{d}{dz} [z^2-9]$

$\lim_{z \to 3i} 2z$ which will give $6i$ but my book says the answer is $0$.

b) $Res(-1)$ for $R(z) = \frac{z^3+4z+9}{(2z+2)(z-3)^5}$

So I solved this by using the formula as well:

$\lim_{z \to -1} \frac{1}{1!} \frac{d}{dz} [(2z+2) \times \frac{z^3+4z+9}{(2z+2)(z-3)^5}]$

$\lim_{z \to -1} [\frac{z^3+4z+9}{(z-3)^5}]$ which I get $\frac{-1}{256}$ but the answer is wrong the correct answer is $\frac{-1}{512}$.

I just don't know where I am wrong?

Comment: Are you using this formula?
$$\operatorname {Res} (c) = \frac 1 {(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac {d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-c)^nf(z))$$

Comment: @player3236 , yes

Comment: never mind I solved it, seen my tiny error.